# Cronbach's Alpha table in R

Tags: r

I have a survey that has 20 questions. Every 5 questions goes into a composite index. I want to calculate Cronbach's Alpha for each index, and hopefully see them all in one table, like this.

```
      Index1   Index2   Index3
Alpha    .3       .9        .4
```

I can figure out how to do this for each index individually:

```
cronbach(x[,1:5])
```

but not as a table. I think this shows I'm not understanding a really basic tenent of R, so please feel free suggest things I should look into.

Thanks!

Comment: A data sample would be helpful. Please read [Help Center: How to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

If the data is stored in a matrix "x", you can form a 3-dimensional array "A" and then use "apply":

```
library(psy)
library(data.table)

#############################################
# Example data:
set.seed(1)
x <- matrix(sample(1:100,200,replace=TRUE),10,20)
#############################################
# cronbach-Test:
A  <- array(x,c(nrow(x),5,ncol(x)/5))
cbTest <- apply(A,3,"cronbach")
setDT(cbTest)
setnames(cbTest,colnames(cbTest),paste(rep("Index",dim(A)[3]),1:(dim(A)[3])))
#############################################
# Result: 
cbTest
#############################################
# Just for comparison:
cronbach(x[,1:5])
cronbach(x[,6:10])
cronbach(x[,11:15])
cronbach(x[,16:20])
```

"A[,,1]" is the matrix "x[,1:5]", "A[,,2]" the matrix "x[,6:11]", and so on. "apply" along the third dimension applies the Cronbach-Test to each of these matrices and forms a list "cbTest". Then "setDT" turns this list into a table:

```
> #############################################
> # Result: 
> cbTest
     Index 1   Index 2   Index 3   Index 4
1:        10        10        10        10
2:         5         5         5         5
3: -0.983849 -3.324005 0.3437152 -3.317533

> #############################################
> # Just for comparison:
> cronbach(x[,1:5])
$sample.size
[1] 10

$number.of.items
[1] 5

$alpha
[1] -0.983849


> cronbach(x[,6:10])
$sample.size
[1] 10

$number.of.items
[1] 5

$alpha
[1] -3.324005


> cronbach(x[,11:15])
$sample.size
[1] 10

$number.of.items
[1] 5

$alpha
[1] 0.3437152


> cronbach(x[,16:20])
$sample.size
[1] 10

$number.of.items
[1] 5

$alpha
[1] -3.317533

>
```

Here is the matrix "x" I used in this example:

```
> x
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13]
 [1,]   27   21   94   49   83   48   92   34   44    24    66    98   100
 [2,]   38   18   22   60   65   87   30   84   72     6    36    74    50
 [3,]   58   69   66   50   79   44   46   35   40    65    28    36    49
 [4,]   91   39   13   19   56   25   34   34   33    88   100    44    18
 [5,]   21   77   27   83   53    8   66   48   76    78    64    15    76
 [6,]   90   50   39   67   79   10   26   90   21    80    22     2    46
 [7,]   95   72    2   80    3   32   48   87   72    46    13    72    52
 [8,]   67  100   39   11   48   52   77   39   13    42    48    11    21
 [9,]   63   39   87   73   74   67    9   78   25    82    93    45    23
[10,]    7   78   35   42   70   41   88   97   15    61    60    65    60
      [,14] [,15] [,16] [,17] [,18] [,19] [,20]
 [1,]    58    69    62    29    64    30    72
 [2,]     8    61    56    90    85    20    39
 [3,]     4    24    33    45    86    89    11
 [4,]    65    26    46    78    40    51    93
 [5,]    93    73    51    89    39    88    29
 [6,]    60    46    19    42    90    19    60
 [7,]    57    18    53     7    65    76    12
 [8,]    53    75     8    34    75    73    85
 [9,]    99    11    28    73    61    95    32
[10,]    51    87    22    34    91    55    79
>
```

And this is the Array "A":

```
> A
, , 1

      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
 [1,]   27   21   94   49   83
 [2,]   38   18   22   60   65
 [3,]   58   69   66   50   79
 [4,]   91   39   13   19   56
 [5,]   21   77   27   83   53
 [6,]   90   50   39   67   79
 [7,]   95   72    2   80    3
 [8,]   67  100   39   11   48
 [9,]   63   39   87   73   74
[10,]    7   78   35   42   70

, , 2

      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
 [1,]   48   92   34   44   24
 [2,]   87   30   84   72    6
 [3,]   44   46   35   40   65
 [4,]   25   34   34   33   88
 [5,]    8   66   48   76   78
 [6,]   10   26   90   21   80
 [7,]   32   48   87   72   46
 [8,]   52   77   39   13   42
 [9,]   67    9   78   25   82
[10,]   41   88   97   15   61

, , 3

      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
 [1,]   66   98  100   58   69
 [2,]   36   74   50    8   61
 [3,]   28   36   49    4   24
 [4,]  100   44   18   65   26
 [5,]   64   15   76   93   73
 [6,]   22    2   46   60   46
 [7,]   13   72   52   57   18
 [8,]   48   11   21   53   75
 [9,]   93   45   23   99   11
[10,]   60   65   60   51   87

, , 4

      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
 [1,]   62   29   64   30   72
 [2,]   56   90   85   20   39
 [3,]   33   45   86   89   11
 [4,]   46   78   40   51   93
 [5,]   51   89   39   88   29
 [6,]   19   42   90   19   60
 [7,]   53    7   65   76   12
 [8,]    8   34   75   73   85
 [9,]   28   73   61   95   32
[10,]   22   34   91   55   79

>
```

Comment: I think using `data.table` is not necessary in this case, and a bit more complicated than using `data.frame`s for beginners. Also keep in mind that forming an array in the way you describe assumes that the columns are ordered per scale.

Comment: Interesting that there is still someone who prefers data.frame to data.table. And what does it mean that the columns are ordered per scale? It cannot be a big deal, if the transformation of a random matrix works smoothly. My idea isn't as bad as all that, is it?

Comment: No, it's not bad at all! I was just saying that, in order to call `array` in this way, there must be exactly the same number of items per scale, and the items must be directly adjacent to each other. Otherwise, `array` will not yield the intended result. As per `data.table`, I use it myself, but I prefer having as few dependencies as possible. For R beginners, a `data.frame` is more convenient in my experience.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. If I'm understanding the "ordered per scale" correctly, then you mean that the five questions that make up index 1 are not 1:5. This is true, I'll probably have something like: Index 1 = 1,2,5. Index 2 = 3,4,7,8,10. Etc... So each index could have a different number of questions that are not adjacent.